# Youtube IFrame file protocol error using Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, youtube

Trying to port our existing site to a Cordova App. We are using the YouTube IFrame API to create a player with which we dynamically load different videos.

Relevant part of config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="Yes" />
```

Safari is throwing the following error somewhere in the call *new YT.Player()*:

**Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.**

We get error code 150 whenever we try to load a video after that. Having a hard time wrapping my head around the error and what is happening.

Comment: The postMessage that YouTube uses to communicate with the container document is causing this issue. If you have a server of your own, you might want to wrap the YouTube iframe inside another iframe whose source is your server. I have not tried it, so caveat emptor

Comment: You might want to look at this thread, it is related https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5670

Comment: Hmm, couldn't find a solution in that thread but thanks for the help. Will look into wrapping our iframe inside another from our server.